# Error while running sqlite3 on ubuntu sqlite3: symbol lookup error: sqlite3: undefined symbol: sqlite3_sourceid

Tags: sqlite, ubuntu-14.04

Error while running sqlite3 on ubuntu I am getting below error message
sqlite3: symbol lookup error: sqlite3: undefined symbol: sqlite3_sourceid.

Ubntu version::
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04

dp8238:~$ sqlite3
sqlite3: symbol lookup error: sqlite3: undefined symbol: sqlite3_sourceid
Codename:   trusty

Comment: Please add more details on versions and full error

Comment: Did you compile or install anything yourself?

Comment: I have removed sqlite3 and install again,Hower i had tried some command by searching online
 1435  sudo apt-get install sqlite3 
 1437  sudo apt-get install spatialite-bin 
 1441  sudo apt-get purge spatialite-bin 
 1443  sudo apt-get install sqlite3
 1444  spatialite test-2.3.sqlite
 1446  spatialite test-2.3.sqlite
 1454  spatialite  spatialite: symbol lookup error: spatialite: undefined symbol: sqlite3_sourceid